# VINCULAR JAVASCRIPT CON CSS

Tags: javascript, css

disculpen, es la primera vez que hago una vinculación y se me presenta el que quiero que se me muestre una ventana cuando los datos no han sido registrados correctamente y otra cuando ya se hayan guardado los datos.

Mi duda es que no sé como vincularlos, ya que no me aparece error pero también  no me muestra mi *javascript*; si alguien me pudiera ayudar para saber en que me estoy equivocando o que me hace falta por hacer se lo agradecería mucho.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const serializeForm = () => {
        const dataArray = $('#form-captura-de-datos').serializeArray();
        const output = {};
        dataArray.forEach((field) => {
            output[field.name] = field.value;
        });
        return output;
    };

    $('#form-captura-de-datos').on('submit', function(e) {
        // Paramos el comportamiento del formulario
        e.preventDefault();

        // Validaciones
        const { nombre, apellido, email, curp } = serializeForm();
        /*var expRegEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"\']+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"\']+)*)|("[^"\']+"))@((\[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\d\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var expRegCurp = /^[A-Z][AEIOUX][A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][MH][A-Z][BCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ]{4}[0-9A-Z][0-9]\z$/;
*/
        let errores = '';

        let nombre = $('#nombre').val().trim();
        if (nombre == '' || nombre.length >= 30) {
            //if (nombre === '' || nombre.length >= 30) {
            errores += '<p>El nombre no debe quedar vacío ni tener más de 30 caracteres.</p>';
            $('#nombre').css('border-bottom-color', '#F14B4B');
        } else {
            $('#nombre').css('border-bottom-color', '#d1d1d1');
        }

        // Validado Apellido ==============================
        //if ($('#apellido').val() == '' || $('#apellido').val() >= 30) {
        let apellido = $('#apellido').val().trim();
        if (apellido == '' || apellido.length >= 30) {
            errores += '<p>El apellido no debe quedar vacío ni tener más de 30 caracteres.</p>'
            $('#apellido').css('border-bottom-color', '#F14B4B');
        } else {
            $('#apellido').css('border-bottom-color', '#d1d1d1');
        }

        // Validado Correo ==============================

        //  var esValido = expRegEmail.test($('#email'));
        let email = $('#email').val().trim();
        if (email == '' || email.length >= 30) {
            errores += '<p>Ingresa una cuenta de correo electrónico válida.</p>';
            $('#email').css('border-bottom-color', '#F14B4B');
        } else {
            $('#email').css('border-bottom-color', '#d1d1d1');
        }


        // ENVIANDO MENSAJE ============================
        if (errores) {
            const mensajeModal =
                '<div class="modal_wrap">' +
                '<div class="mensaje_modal">' +
                '<h3>Errores encontrados</h3>' +
                errores +
                '<span id="btnClose">Cerrar</span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            $('body').append(mensajeModal);
            // CERRANDO MODAL ==============================
            $('#btnClose').click(function() {
                $('.modal_wrap').remove();
            });
        } else {
            // Continuamos con la petición
            e.currentTarget.submit();

             const mensajeModalA =
                 '<div class="modal_wrap_a">' +
                 '<div class="mensaje_modal_a">' +
                 '<h3>Datos guardados correctamente</h3>'
             '<span id="btnClose_a">Cerrar</span>' +
             '</div>' +
             '</div>';
             $('body').append(mensajeModalA);
             // CERRANDO MODAL ==============================
             $('#btnClose_a').click(function() {
                 $('.modal_wrap_a').remove();
             });
        }


    });
});
```

```css
/* Ventana de errores*/

.modal_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.mensaje_modal {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px 20px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.mensaje_modal h3:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C5C5C5;
    margin: 10px 0px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #606060;
}

.mensaje_modal p:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #E25151;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#btnClose {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #E25151;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #B14141;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}


/* Ventana de mensaje bien*/

.modal_wrap_a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.mensaje_modal_a {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px 20px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal_a h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.mensaje_modal_a h3:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C5C5C5;
    margin: 10px 0px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal_a p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #606060;
}

.mensaje_modal_a p:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #E25151;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#btnClose_a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #E25151;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #B14141;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Sugiero que incluyas el _HTML_ del formulario y de la ventana de errores. Ideal sería crear un [mcve].

Comment: Probablemente tu html no está linkeando a tu css o Al JavaScript la ruta puede ser invalida tambien. Añade tu html y te podria ayudar mejor